# Javascript Form for Calculating Cost of Semester Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to create a seemingly simple form. But for some reason I can not get it to work. I know this should be an easy task for entry-level javascripters but I can't figure it out. I've tried many solutions today but I have not been able to get it to work. Any help you guys could give would be greatly appreciated :)

I'm trying to build a form that estimates the cost of a skipped class:

(http://jsfiddle.net/Gt2vK/2/)

```
function calculateCost() {
    // enter annual tuition
    var $annualTuition = parseInt($('#annual_tuition').val(), 10);
    // tuition per semester
    var semesterTuition = $annualTuition / 3;
    // total number of credits for semester
    var $semesterCredits = parseInt($('#semester_credits').val(), 10);
    // cost of a single credit
    var singleCreditCost = semesterTuition / $semesterCredits;
    // total credits for class being skipped
    var $skippedTotalCredits = parseInt($('#skipped_total_credits').val(), 10);
    // total cost for class being skipped
    var skippedTotalCreditsCost = $skippedTotalCredits * singleCreditCost;
    // total number of days in semester for class being skipped
    var $skippedTotalDays = parseInt($('#skipped_total_days').val(), 10);
    // (total cost of class) / (total number of class days in semester) = cost of class
    var skippedSingleClassCost = skippedTotalCreditsCost / $skippedTotalDays;
}​

$(function(){

    $('#cost').on('click', function(){
        $('#costTotal').html(calculateCost);
        // why the heck doesnt this work?!?
        alert(calculateCost);
    });

});
```

and my html:

```
<form id="costForm" action="#" onsubmit="#">

    <div>
        <label for="annual_tuition">Annual Tuition:</label>
        <input type="text" name="annual_tuition" id="annual_tuition" value="" tabindex="1">
     </div>

        <div>
        <label for="semester_credits">Semester Credits</label>
        <input type="text" name="semester_credits" id="semester_credits" value="" tabindex="1">
     </div>

     <div>
        <label for="skipped_total_credits">Skipped Total Credits</label>
        <input type="text" name="skipped_total_credits" id="skipped_total_credits" value="" tabindex="1">
     </div>

        <div>
        <label for="skipped_total_days">Skipped Total Days</label>
        <input type="text" name="skipped_total_days" id="skipped_total_days" value="" tabindex="1">
     </div>

    <div>
         <button id="cost" type="button" >Calculate</button>
    </div>

    <div id="costTotal"></div>

</form>
```

Comment: 1) I don't see `calculateCost` being called anywhere. 2) Those variables only exist within the scope of the function, so they are not accessible outside. If you need a value from the function, you should call the function and return the value. Am I perhaps missing something?

Comment: don't try and fire your onclick event on a "submit" button.  use a button button.

Comment: doh! sorry (I don't know what I'm doing )

Comment: k, I updated the code per your comments so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're onclick event wire up isn't correct, I've changed it:

```
<div> 
       <button id="cost" type="button">Calculate</button>
 </div>
```

Change your javascript:

```
function calculateCost() {
 // enter annual tuition
 var $annualTuition = parseInt($('#annual_tuition').val(), 10);
 // tuition per semester
 var semesterTuition = $annualTuition / 3;
 // total number of credits for semester
 var $semesterCredits = parseInt($('#semester_credits').val(), 10);
 // cost of a single credit
 var singleCreditCost = semesterTuition / $semesterCredits;
 // total credits for class being skipped
 var $skippedTotalCredits = parseInt($('#skipped_total_credits').val(), 10);
 // total cost for class being skipped
 var skippedTotalCreditsCost = $skippedTotalCredits * singleCreditCost;
 // total number of days in semester for class being skipped
 var $skippedTotalDays = parseInt($('#skipped_total_days').val(), 10);
 // (total cost of class) / (total number of class days in semester) = cost of class
 var skippedSingleClassCost = skippedTotalCreditsCost / $skippedTotalDays;
 return skippedSingleClassCost ;
}​
    $("#cost").click( function()
       {
         $('#costTotal').html(calculateCost());
   //      alert(calculateCost());
       }
    );
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion here, but maybe I did something wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/Gt2vK/4/

Comment: yeah, I'm playing with it too.. one other thing is your calculate function needs to return a value.

Comment: i can't get the button to fire the method for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Change calculateCost() to **`return`** what would've been `skippedSingleClassCost` and then change your references to `skippedSingleClassCost` to be `calculateCost()`.

Pasted into your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gt2vK/6/)

```
function calculateCost() {
    // enter annual tuition
    var $annualTuition = parseInt($('#annual_tuition').val(), 10);
    // tuition per semester
    var semesterTuition = $annualTuition / 3;
    // total number of credits for semester
    var $semesterCredits = parseInt($('#semester_credits').val(), 10);
    // cost of a single credit
    var singleCreditCost = semesterTuition / $semesterCredits;
    // total credits for class being skipped
    var $skippedTotalCredits = parseInt($('#skipped_total_credits').val(), 10);
    // total cost for class being skipped
    var skippedTotalCreditsCost = $skippedTotalCredits * singleCreditCost;
    // total number of days in semester for class being skipped
    var $skippedTotalDays = parseInt($('#skipped_total_days').val(), 10);
    // (total cost of class) / (total number of class days in semester) = cost of class
    return skippedTotalCreditsCost / $skippedTotalDays;
}

$(function(){

    $('#cost').on('click', function(){
        $('#costTotal').html(calculateCost());
        // why the heck doesnt this work?!?
        alert(calculateCost());
    });

});
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution here - http://jsfiddle.net/Gt2vK/5/, any idea why it wouldnt work?

Comment: Not sure what went wrong in yours, but just copied the javascript above and it seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/Gt2vK/6/

Comment: @StupidDev - most def. gonna be many basic mistakes, sorry - trying my best to get to your level. thanks for your answer.

Comment: what were some of the mistakes (other than no return statement) and the click event...